# Laravel hasMany and belongsToMany relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have struggled with my Laravel relationships.

So I have 3 tables:

1. Users
2. Countries
3. countries_user

As you can see relation is countries_user. Now every time gives error like:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
> 1054 Unknown column 'countries.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select
>
> - from `countries` where `countries`.`user_id` = 1 and `countries`.`user_id` is not null) in file
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gManager\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php
>   on line 671

I understand the problem is that it's looking in countries and not in countries_user. How to define where I want to search the relation?

Here is my User model

```
public function countries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Countries');
    }
```

And my Countries Model

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO... Pls post the code for your Model relationships

Comment: What query is giving you the error

Comment: in a many-to-many relationship you should use belongsToMany in both models. hasMany is for a one-to-many relationship, so it will directly look at your countries, instead of using the pivot

Comment: It's giving  SQLSTATE[42S22]

Comment: No I mean the code for query you are trying to run

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the table name

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'countries_user');
}
```

And the inverse relation should also be belongsToMany

```php
public function countries()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Countries::class, 'countries_user');
}
```

And also specify the table property on Countries model

```php
class Countries extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'countries';

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `countries` relationship should be `belongsToMany` too.
Instead of

```
public function countries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Countries');
    }
```

put

```
public function countries()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Countries');
    }
```

Comment: It was like that before. Thank you! I realized that I made mistake with controller.

Comment: glad i was able to help you. Please mark as resoled